Determining uniformly sized cells of a triangular graph over an ellipsoid
I have a series of undirected graphs, labelled $0..n$, which are formed from dividing the faces of an octahedron into $9$ icosahedral sub-triangles, such that the number of triangles to each face is $9^n$.
This graph is then projected onto an ellipsoid (WGS84).  I am trying to derive the positions of the graph such that most of the cells are as icosahedral as they can be, and that the cells are uniformly sized .
I have been using Kamada & Kawai's force-directed approach to this problem, and have managed to harness their algorithm in Boost, which allows one to define their own topology (so I am using GeographicLib for that).
Here is a visualisation showing it works reasonably well for $n=3$, albeit the four cells around the each of the 6 vertices of the octahedron have small areas.

However, the process is computationally expensive and, being a general algorithm, doesn't seem to lend itself well to the underlying pattern of the graph.
I now think I should be using Lloyd's algorithm - which will give me well-shaped and uniformly sized convex cells, but before I start researching how to do that, maybe a mathematician here could suggest a more straightforward approach, bearing in mind that two vertices of the octahedron is fixed to the semi-minor axis, and being founded on an octahedron, the network has a three planes of symmetry.
